# Cakephp 2.0: complex find query

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I'm trying to pull some info out of two tables linked by the hasMany and belongsTo associations.

requisitions hasMany locations and locations belongsTo requisitions

```
TABLE `requisitions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`fecha_generacion` date NOT NULL,
`solicitado_a` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`proyecto` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`obra_no` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`observaciones` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

and 
  TABLE `locations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `requisition_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `name` enum('pendiente','tecnico','existencia','cotizando','generar_o','archivada')   
   NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pendiente',
  `image_path` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'estado0.png',
  `note` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Requisition goes from one Location to another and I need to keep track of its current Location looking by a given Location as 'pendiente','tecnico'...
So I need to generate a list with the last Location for each Requisition and then filter that list by the Location.name

I believe the only way to do this is with a query around another query, so I'm trying to understand cakephp syntax with more simple queries first.

I was trying to search for the last 'pendiente' Location with the next code from my RequisitionsController.

```
$lastPendiente = $this->Requisition->Location->find('all', array(
 'conditions' => array('Location.name' => 'pendiente'),
   'fields' => array('MAX(Location.id) AS olderLocation', 'Location.requisition_id'), 
    'group' => 'Requisition.id',
    ));
```

I have the query

```
SELECT MAX(`Location`.`id`) AS olderLocation, `Location`.`requisition_id` FROM `petrofil_demo`.`locations` AS `Location` LEFT JOIN `petrofil_demo`.`requisitions` AS `Requisition` ON (`Location`.`requisition_id` = `Requisition`.`id`) WHERE `Location`.`name` = 'pendiente' GROUP BY `Requisition`.`id`
```

output...

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'olderLocation' => '22'
        ),
        'Location' => array(
            'requisition_id' => '29'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'olderLocation' => '5'
        ),
        'Location' => array(
            'requisition_id' => '30'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'olderLocation' => '13'
        ),
        'Location' => array(
            'requisition_id' => '31'
        )
    )
)
```

...which is great because those are exactly the last requisitions with a 'pendiente' location but here comes the second query or the condition where I'm clueless. I need to be sure my requisition last state was 'pendiente' and not another possible locations. For example my requisition_id =>30 last location is really 'tecnico' so I need to find a way to exclude it from showing on my results.

Answer (score 0):

You could quit the condition from the query, put the 'name' column in the 'fields' and add an order by sentence:

```
    $lastPendiente = $this->Requisition->Location->find('all', array(
   'fields' => array('MAX(Location.id) AS olderLocation', 'Location.requisition_id', 'name'), 
    'group' => 'Requisition.id',
    'order' => 'fecha DESC'
    ));
```

This way you only get the last status from the Location table. Then, you could iterate the results, filtering by the 'name' column and deleting those whit a 'name' diferent from 'pendiente':

```
foreach($lastPendiente as $k => $location){
if($location['Location']['name'] != 'pendiente'){
    unset($lastPendiente[$k]);
}
```